# Using Datapager in case of paged results

Tags: asp.net

Before I explain the problem, let me set the context. I have a stored procedure which returns me paged results. So if I mentioned the page number as 1, I get the first 10 records and if the page number is 2 I get the next 10 set of records and so on.

Now in my Asp.Net page I need to show 10 items at a time and I want the pagination to be in numbered style. The same like Google pagination.

The problem now is that, since I get only 10 records at a time from the DB, the numbers don't show up. I've come across a solution at: [How to use DataPager with Database Paged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447130/how-to-use-datapager-with-database-paged), however since my total number of records can run into 100's or 1000's, running the loop for so long is again a performance issue.

It would be great if you can let me know how this issue can be fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you presenting the data output by the sproc? GridView and similar controls can implement paging with page numbers as you describe, have you tried just wiring a GridView up to the sproc's output and let it handle the pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Tweak your stored procedure to add an output parameter that returns the total number of records that will be returned without pagination. You can then use that number to create your pager controls.